# Using BigQuery for AdSense data - 403 Access Denied

Tags: google-bigquery, adsense-api

I've been successfully using BigQuery to pull AdSense data, but recently all queries have started failing, with this error:

> (403) Access Denied: Table
>   google.com:adsense-reports:Reports.DailyCustomChannelReport: The user
>   does not have permission to query a table in dataset
>   google.com:adsense-reports:Reports

Here's a sample query:

`SELECT matched_ad_requests, clicks, FROM [google.com:adsense-reports:Reports.DailyCustomChannelReport] WHERE date BETWEEN '2015-02-10' AND '2015-02-11'AND custom_channel_code like 'test_18'`

- These query failures aren't associated with any code change to my application. They also fail in the BigQuery browser tool- even queries that ran successfully in the past. This seems to rule out a problem with the query.
- Nothing has changed with regards to my account access to AdSense. I am able to log in to the dashboard and see all data.

Any ideas how I can restore my ability to query this data? Thanks.

Comment: It's possible that this integration is not working anymore. Investigating

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Thanks for responding, I'm wondering if your investigation turned up anything?

Answer (score 0):

I got internal confirmation: The AdSense experiment for BigQuery was discontinued. The team tells me they notified the experiment users some months ago, before disabling it.

Sorry for the lack of better news!